# PropTypes en React, no me esta funcionando

Tags: javascript, webpack, reactjs

Lo primero, ya había usado el paquete de ***prop-types*** antes para validar argumentos en componentes de **React**, pero en un proyecto en específico no se porque no me esta funcionando y lo tengo configurado como siempre.
Uso **WebPack** para el bundle y el servidor de pruebas ***(webpack-dev-server)***

Esta es mi cabecera:

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const PropTypes = require('prop-types');
```

Y aqui el componente padre, el hijo y los PropTypes:

```
    class IssueTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const borderedStyle = {border: "1px solid blue", padding: 6};

    return (
      <table style={{borderCollapse: "collapse"}}>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th style={borderedStyle}>Id</th>
            <th style={borderedStyle}>Title</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <IssueRow issue_id={1}
                   issue_title="Error in console" />
         <IssueRow issue_id={2}
                   issue_title="Error in console 2" />
       </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}


class IssueRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const borderedStyle = {border: "1px solid red", padding: 4};
    return (
      <tr>
        <td style={borderedStyle}>{this.props.issue_id}</td>
        <td style={borderedStyle}>{this.props.issue_title}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}

IssueRow.PropTypes =  {
    issue_id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    issue_title: PropTypes.string
};
```

Lo raro es que no obtengo ningún error en consola y me renderiza correctamente la tabla, pero en el momento que en el atributo "id" le paso un string en vez de un numero no me salta el warning del PropTypes.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que tienes, un error o warning? ¿Cuál es este?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que tienes es porque tienes una `P` (mayúscula) en `IssueRow.PropTypes`.

Debes escribir la declaración de los PropTypes así:

```
IssueRow.propTypes =  {
    issue_id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    issue_title: PropTypes.string
};
```

Esto se debe a que PropTypes es el paquete que estás importando y propTypes es la propiedad de los tipos de datos de tu clase.

Hay otra forma de declarar los PropTypes (la cual uso yo) y es la siguiente:

Dentro de tu clase, antes del constructor:

```
static propTypes =  {
  issue_id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  issue_title: PropTypes.string
}
```

¿Por qué no importas los paquetes de React y demás con la sintaxis de ES6?

Saludos.

Comment: Hey gracias, hacía tiempo que había hecho esta pregunta. En esos tiempos no estaba familiarizado con la sintaxis de ES6 al completo y desconocía los imports por eso no lo utilize, ya he solucionado el error de typo :)